# st_url is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, html, sharethis

I am using sharethis in my application.

here is my code

```
<a style="transition: none;" ng-init="initShare()" class="st_sharethis_custom"   ng-if="loggedIn"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="/*font-size: 29px;*/"></i><em>SHARE</em></a>
```

this code works (it gives me the current url and shares)

but now i want to dynamic url so i am adding st_url for my code.

here is the code

```
<a style="transition: none;" ng-init="initShare()" class="st_sharethis_custom" st_url="#page/{{page.Id}}"  ng-if="loggedIn"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="/*font-size: 29px;*/"></i><em>SHARE</em></a>
```

now the problem is the url is taking as "#page/{{page.Id}}" it is not replacing with the base url and with the pageId.

I even tried the full url with pageId (https:/..../page/{{page.Id}})

even this not taking the value of pageId.

can anyone help me with this thanks in advance

Comment: May I know what is `st_url`.

Comment: @Sai hello st_url is an additional parameters which will be used for sharing url. Here is the url https://support.sharethis.com/hc/en-us/articles/218441477-How-to-Customize-which-URL-Text-and-IMG-to-Share